# runtime error: member access within null pointer

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, nodes, priority-queue

> i am trying to solve the 'Merge k sorted linked lists and return it as one sorted list' question on leetcode
>
> this is my code:-

```
class Solution {
public:
    struct compare
    {
        bool operator()(Node *l, Node *r)
        {
           return l->val > r->val;
        }
        
    };
    ListNode* mergeKLists(vector<ListNode*>& lists) 
    {
        priority_queue<Node*, vector<Node*>, compare> q;
        for(auto l: lists)
        {
            q.push(l);
        }
        if(q.empty()) return nullptr;
        Node *head, *header;
        head = q.top();
        header = head;
        
        q.pop();
        
        if(head->next) q.push(head->next);
        
        
        while(!q.empty())
        {
            head->next = q.top();
            q.pop();
            cout << head->next->val << endl;
            head = head->next;
            if(head->next)
            {
                q.push(head->next);
            }
        }
        return header;
        
        
    }
};
```

> this is the error that i am getting
>
> Line 36: Char 18: runtime error: member access within null pointer of type 'ListNode' (solution.cpp)
> SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:45:18

Comment: It would help if you told us what line was 36.

Comment: I hate to be unhelpful, but this is probably one of those cases where you'd find it yourself a lot faster with a debugger than we can by staring at the code.

Comment: There are two unchecked accesses to `head->next` in the `while` loop.

Comment: @dxiv head->next is q.top() which is always not null so why and what to check exactly ?

Comment: @dagwood `q.top() which is always not null` Not necessarily so after `q.pop()`.